# pandoc-crossref missing top-level section number in reference to subsubsection

Tags: cross-referencing, pandoc

In the following Pandoc markdown document, `pandoc-crossref` incorrectly assigns the section number `1.1` instead of `2.1.1` to the reference to `sec:first-background-subsubsection` (level=3). The reference to `sec:second-background-subsection` -- which becomes `2.2` -- is handled correctly by `pandoc-crossref` (level=2). It seems, generally, that `pandoc-crossref` only keeps the last two section numbers, i.e. cutting off e.g. `1.2.3.4` to just `3.4`.

Pandoc markdown:

```
# Introduction

* A reference to a section of depth 3: @sec:first-background-subsubsection.
* A reference to a section of depth 2: @sec:second-background-subsection.
* A reference to a section of depth 4: @sec:deepest-subsection.

# Background

Here's the background.

## First Background-subsection

Here's a the first subsection in the Background-section.

### Some subsubsection {#sec:first-background-subsubsection}

Here's a subsubsection.

### Ignore this subsubsection

#### Deepest subsection {#sec:deepest-subsection}

A level-four subsection.

## Second Background-subsection {#sec:second-background-subsection}

Here's a the second subsection in the Background-section.
```

Pandoc command used to build .tex file:

`pandoc --standalone --from markdown -F pandoc-crossref --pdf-engine=xelatex input.md -o output.tex`

LateX output for the **Introduction** section:

```
\section{Introduction}\label{introduction}}

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  A reference to a section of depth 3: sec.~1.1.
\item
  A reference to a section of depth 2: sec.~2.2.
\item
  A reference to a section of depth 4: sec.~2.1.
\end{itemize}
```

Version info:

- pandoc 2.9.2.1 (Compiled with pandoc-types 1.20, texmath 0.12.0.1, skylighting 0.8.3.2)
- pandoc-crossref v0.4.0.0 git commit 80080744cec5c9d0696d4e4be77bec5fc1cc2375 (HEAD) built with Pandoc v2.9.2.1, pandoc-types v1.20 and GHC 8.8.3

Comment: Your output should consist in `\ref` or `\cref`  commands and numbering should be done by latex. Since you are using a alpha version of `pandoc-crossref` I'd suggest reporting the issue: https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref/issues

Comment: When I run your code with `pandoc-crossref v0.3.6.2` the output is as expected. Although you have to add the option  `--number-sections` to work.

Comment: @runeks I face the exact same problem as you. Could you solve this ?

Comment: @Mary No, I never managed to solve it. I ended up not using `pandoc-crossref` but instead `\ref` (as recommended by @DG') hereby letting Latex do the numbering (which worked like a charm, but constrained me to Latex output only).